# FCM-Push Notification via AWS-SNS got delay or have to open screen for receiving notification

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, amazon-sns

I got some problem to share with, I've been testing push mobile notification via AWS-SNS push noti service and it works properly when my app is on **foreground** or **background** my notification almost come instant time after publishing but, there are some cases that may bug my app/works.

When my app had been killed from foreground or no interaction with my phone for a while(around minutes), notification that was sent from SNS then to FCM got **delay** and sometimes It **required opening(wake up screen)** mobile then notification will show up after that. This was weird and interesting at the same time.

What I have done so far:
I come through fcm doc spec - setting `high` priority to my noti message then my payload look likes,

```
{"data":{"payload":{}}, "priority":"high", "android":{"priority":"high"}}
```

I've set priority key to follow *legacy HTTP API* and *HTTP v1 API* already(Yes, I test with both cases) but, the behavior still got an issue

***I tested on Huawei phone, Android 8.0.1

**NOTE:** For APN, IOS works properly and I am so new to mobile dev so, feel free to suggest anything to me

Thank you in advance.